# Guided LDA in GenSim with fixed Eta

Tags: python, gensim, lda

I wanted to fix topics to include some words, e.g. 
Topic 0 - cloud_computing,hybrid_cloud, ...
Topic 1 - smartphone,mobile, ...

So I can across this blog http://scignconsulting.com/2019/03/09/guided-lda/ which attempts to do just that by settings priors for eta.

But what I've found is that for large collections of documents (10s of 1000s) the seed words are getting downranked, with only 5/104 of the final topics actually including any of the original seed words.

I have a hypothesis for why this is happening. I believe that the alphas for the probability of a topic given a document would also need to be set, otherwise, if the probability for a seeded topic is very low, the seedwords may not matter much at all.

Has anyone had experience in this or any pointers to avoid the seed words being ignored.

Comment: It is better to share the example of code, so we can know what libraries and parameters you used for your model.

Answer (score 2):

maybe it is too late for the answer, but in case if someone also will face the same issue:

1) Think if you really need to keep your custom words are the most important for topic consideration, and if you are sure you want this, go to the next step.

2) Try to remove normalization for eta, it helped in my case.

So, I've tried an example from this article https://gist.github.com/scign/2dda76c292ef76943e0cd9ff8d5a174a

And I also noted that my keywords are not in "top 10" important keywords for topics, so I removed the line from function "create_eta":

```
eta = np.divide(eta, eta.sum(axis=0))
```

and now my custom words are at the top of the words list for the topics.

If you are reading this and you think my suggestion is a bad idea please let me know :)

Comment: your suggestion helped but it shoots up the perplexity...In my case in gets into something like 5656.090900 instead of being something like -1.6789...what would be relation between perplexity and priori based eta

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use Seeded LDA: https://github.com/koheiw/seededlda

If you want to stick to the current library, note that the prior only determines the starting condition for topic modeling. That is, how your topics look like when you begin, but while running the algorithm the prior is "overruled" by learning from data. So whether any words end up in any topic is mostly determined by the data (the prior has some impact but not in an easily predictable manner).

You can do some hacking to fix this, though this somehow breaks the math behind it, but most likely it still works.
You want to ensure that the most likely words of a topic are your seed words.
So before eta is normalized (e.g. before @Timur line of code). You just set all words eta[i,j] with indexes of your seed words to max eta:

maxVal=np.max(eta)

for i,j in seedWordindexes: eta[i,j]=maxVal